# Spring4 / JUnit4 embedded database not loading, possibly misconfigured project

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4, hsqldb

I *thought* I had everything together but not true, so I ask for help.

I've a small Spring 4 (WebMvc) project that performs CRUD activity on one table in MySQL (in my code, the Location class).  I have it working OK in Spring 4 on Tomcat 8, without unit tests.

Now I add unit tests but can't get my JUnit configuration right.  I think I set up an embedded HSQL database correctly, but my JUnit tests say there are no records.  Can I get someone to straighten me out?

The program isn't actually named "MyProgram", nor is the path "mypackagepath", but editing things to that shortens things.  First, here are the configuration parts of the working program:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackagepath")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyProgramConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { ... }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) { ... }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) { ... }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "mypackagepath.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "mypackagepath.dao" })
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name="entitymanagername")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() { ... }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() { ... }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) { ... }
}

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() { ... }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() { ... }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() { ... }

}
```

Similar configurers in the test code are:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "mypackagepath.configuration" }, 
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = JpaConfiguration.class, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE ) )
public class TestJpaConfiguration {

    @Value("classpath:createLocationTableForTest.sql")
    private String createLocationTableScript;

    @Value("classpath:fillLocationTableForTest.sql")
    private String fillLocationTableScript;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name="myentitymanagername")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("myentitymanagername");
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "mypackagepath.model" });

    JpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    em.afterPropertiesSet();

    return em;
    }

    /*
     * The individual table filling scripts are defined
     * and run in the test classes. 
     */
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")    
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript(createLocationTableScript)
            .addScript(fillLocationTableScript)
            .build();

        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory( this.entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );

    return tm;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", environment.getRequiredProperty("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes"));

    return properties;        
   }

}
```

I have an application.properties file in the main/resources and also in the test/resources directories.  The "test" one has HSQL attributes, of course.

I believe that the records aren't loading (from the fillLocationTableForTest.sql file) because my MySQL version of the test table has a lot of records in it (if the test configuration was being ignored) and the JUnit test fails:

```
@Test
public final void testSummaryCountTotal() {
    Summary summary = summaryDao.getSummary();
    assertThat(summary.getCountTotal(), equalTo(12L));
}
```

This returns java.lang.AssertionError: Expected <12L> but was <0L> ...

For what it is worth, in my console my JUnit run gives me:

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.web.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.web.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@193948d, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1604f19, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@23a2f9, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@c0edeb, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@17e2f02]
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@dd8682: startup date [Tue Feb 09 03:51:34 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=jpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [mypackagepath/configuration/JpaConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=testJpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in mypackagepath.configuration.TestJpaConfiguration]
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'exceptionTranslation': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=jpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=exceptionTranslation; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [mypackagepath/configuration/JpaConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=testJpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=exceptionTranslation; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in mypackagepath.configuration.TestJpaConfiguration]
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'myentitymanagername': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=jpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=entityManagerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [mypackagepath/configuration/JpaConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=testJpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=entityManagerFactoryBean; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in mypackagepath.configuration.TestJpaConfiguration]
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=jpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [mypackagepath/configuration/JpaConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=testJpaConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in mypackagepath.configuration.TestJpaConfiguration]

[main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'testJpaConfiguration' of type [class mypackagepath.configuration.TestJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9ae76ba] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[main] INFO org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
[main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'myentitymanagername'
INFO : org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: myentitymanagername
    ...]
INFO : org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
INFO : org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.Currency] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CurrencyType@1ffa30b
INFO : org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
INFO : org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000230: Schema export complete
[main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'myentitymanagername'
INFO : org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: myentitymanagername
    ...]

INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.Currency] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CurrencyType@1ffa30b
INFO : org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
INFO : org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000230: Schema export complete
WARN : org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry - HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (myentitymanagername) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//location/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<mypackagepath.model.Location> mypackagepath.controller.LocationController.getEdit(java.lang.Long)
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//location/{id}],methods=[PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<mypackagepath.model.Location> mypackagepath.controller.LocationController.putEdit(mypackagepath.model.Location,java.lang.Long)
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//next/{id}/type/{type}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<mypackagepath.model.Location> mypackagepath.controller.LocationController.getNextEdit(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/main],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String mypackagepath.controller.MainController.getMainPage()
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//address/{address}/{key}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> mypackagepath.controller.ProxyAccessController.getAddress(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/static/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@dd8682: startup date [Tue Feb 09 03:51:34 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[Thread-1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@dd8682: startup date [Tue Feb 09 03:51:34 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[Thread-1] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'myentitymanagername'
```

**My request:** Can someone help me to groom a Spring / JUnit configuration that works on Tomcat and in JUnit?

Thanks, 
Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to my ills, but probably not the best one.  I'm still looking for a better solution.

In my TestJpaConfiguration.dataSource() I remove the addScript() calls:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")    
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        //.addScript(createLocationTableScript)
        //.addScript(fillLocationTableScript)
        .build();

    return db;
}
```

In each test Java file I set up an embedded database in each setUp() / tearDown() pair:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestJpaConfiguration.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SummaryDaoTest {

    @Value("classpath:createLocationTableForTest.sql")
    private String createLocationTableScript;

    @Value("classpath:fillLocationTableForTest.sql")
    private String fillLocationTableScript;

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Autowired
    private SummaryDao summaryDao;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript(createLocationTableScript)
            .addScript(fillLocationTableScript)
            .build();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        db.shutdown();
    }

    // After this come the tests...

}
```

This works for me -- the code passes its JUnit tests, is deployable to Tomcat and works OK there.

Can I get an improvement so I "don't repeat myself" in each test?

Thanks,
Jerome.